# Seg fault on running a program through linker?

Tags: c, linux, linker, segmentation-fault, libc

I downloaded the source for `libc6` and completed the build process successfully. (Though I did not performed a `make install` deliberately).

With the new linker built in `buil-dir/elf/ld.so` I ran a program supplying it as the argument to the newly built linker.

- The test code prints some string and then `malloc(sizeof(char)*1024)`.
- On running the test binary as an argument to the newly built linker I get a `Seg Fault` at `elf/dl-addr.c:132` which is:

  `131   /* Protect against concurrent loads and unloads.  */`

  `132   __rtld_lock_lock_recursive (GL(dl_load_lock));`
- This is the last frame before the seg fault and is called through `malloc()` call from the test program.

Stack Trace at that point :

```
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007f11a6a94928 in __GI__dl_addr (address=0x7f11a69e67a0 <ptmalloc_init>,   info=0x7fffe9393be0, mapp=0x7fffe9393c00, symbolp=0x0) at dl-addr.c:132
#2  0x00007f11a69e64d7 in ptmalloc_init () at arena.c:381
#3  0x00007f11a69e72b8 in ptmalloc_init () at arena.c:371
#4  malloc_hook_ini (sz=<optimized out>, caller=<optimized out>) at hooks.c:32
#5  0x00000000004005b3 in main () at test.c:20
```

On running the same program with the default installed linker on the machine the program runs fine.

- I am not able to understand what can be the issue behind this? (Is it faulting because I am using the newly built linker without installing it first)

-Any suggestions or pointers are highly appreciated.
Thanks

(System details `GCC 4.8.22, eglibc-2.15 Ubuntu 12.10 64bit`

Comment: You should have installed your new libc. However, I believe you are wrong in upgrading it manually. Upgrade your distribution to a more recent version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I have to modify the linker and test it if it is working as per the changes(Right now there are no code changes done in it). Is there a way where I can test the newly built linker for this purpose?

Comment: I would then suggest working in a `chroot`-ed environment where you can install a mini distribution and experiment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With the new linker built in `buil-dir/elf/ld.so` I ran a program supplying it as the argument to the newly built linker.

It that's *all* you did, then the crash is *expected*, because you are mixing newly-built loader with *system* libraries (which doesn't work: *all* parts of `glibc` *must* come from the same build of it).

What you need to do is:

```
buil-dir/elf/ld.so \
  --library-path buil-dir:buil-dir/dlfcn:buil-dir/nptl:... \
  /path/to/a.out
```

The list of directories to search *must* include all the libraries (parts of glibc) that your program uses.

Comment: So I have to basically add all the folder in the build directory as the library path in the command line args while running newly build ld.so

Comment: One quick query- If one of my programs uses libsssl or any other library which is not built as part of libc then in this case do I need to build them again using the newly built libc and linker or the previous one will suffice?

Comment: I am asking this because I have to finally test the modified linker with Apache (httpd) which uses many libraries like libssl, libcrypto etc which are not build as part of Libc. Thanks

Comment: @abhi No: the rule only applies to parts of glibc itself (which all must be from the same build). Other libraries do not need to be rebuilt.